# android videoview set path

Tags: android

i'm trying to play a video through videoview , the video file i put in the

res/raw directory.

so i tried this  :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"logo.mp4");
        splashVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
```

but it can't play , could someone tell me , how should i set my file path in uri??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe instead of logo.mp4 you should be using R.raw.logo

You probably need to add a slash after the package name as well.

Answer (score 0):

i also i found my answer.

it is :

mp4 can not be played on emulator , when i use GT-P1000 run my application ,

it worked fine........Orz

thx all